# spark Scala join multi time of an aggregated table

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes: one contains the feature of people, another contains the data statistics. Two tables look like this:

**df_base:**

```
user_id gender  platform
id1     1       Android
id2     2       Android
id3     1       Android
id4     1       iOS
id5     2       Android
```

**df_time_series:**

```
time_prefix gender  platform    gender_lt7  platform_lt7
m1          1       Android     22486       48185
m1          2       Android     15791       48185
m1          0       Android     18940       48185
m2          0       Android     16401       40852
m2          0       Android     16401       40852
m2          0       iOS         16401       8475
m3          0       Android     15507       39472
m3          1       Android     19205       39472
m3          2       Android     12999       39472
```

The upper dataframe will left join the next dataframe six times in the double for-loop. Here is the code written by python.

```py
def process_time_feature(df_base, df_time_series):
    for time_prefix in ['m1','m2','m3']: 
        time_df = df_time_series[df_time_series['time_prefix']==time_prefix]
        for key in ['gender','platform']:
            df_key_agg = time_df[[key,key+'_lt7']].groupby(key).agg({key+'_lt7':'mean'}).reset_index()
            df_key_agg = df_key_agg.rename(columns={key+'_lt7':key+'_lt7'+'_'+time_prefix})
            df_base = pd.merge(df_base,df_key_agg,on=key,how='left')
    return df_base
```

And the result will look like this and six columns have been added:

[image]

Could someone help me to translate the code into Spark Scala in an elegant and efficient way. My scala code looks like the python one above, and always throws the "Out of memory" exception with more keys and more data.

Here is my scala code. The df_base may have 5,000,000 rows with 100 features. Length of keys is 14, so the df_base will join df_time_series 14*3=52 times.

```scala
val agg_cols = List("gender", "platform")
val df_time_m1 = df_time_series.filter(col("time_prefix") === "m1")
val df_time_m2 = df_time_series.filter(col("time_prefix") === "m2")
val df_time_m3 = df_time_series.filter(col("time_prefix") === "m3")
val time_prefixs = List("m1", "m2", "m3")
time_prefixs.map(println)
val result = agg_cols.foldLeft(df_base)((df_base, key) => {
  df_base
    .alias("p")
    .join(
      df_time_m1.groupBy(key).agg((key + "_lt7", "mean")).withColumnRenamed("avg(" + key + "_lt7)", key + "_lt7_" + "m1").alias("c"),
      col("p." + key) === col("c." + key), "left_outer"
    ).drop(col("c." + key))
    .join(
      df_time_m2.groupBy(key).agg((key + "_lt7", "mean")).withColumnRenamed("avg(" + key + "_lt7)", key + "_lt7_" + "m2").alias("c"),
      col("p." + key) === col("c." + key), "left_outer"
    ).drop(col("c." + key))
    .join(
      df_time_m3.groupBy(key).agg((key + "_lt7", "mean")).withColumnRenamed("avg(" + key + "_lt7)", key + "_lt7_" + "m3").alias("c"),
      col("p." + key) === col("c." + key), "left_outer"
    ).drop(col("c." + key))
})
```

Comment: Can you paste your current attempt in Scala? How many keys and data do you need to handle?

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy hello, I have updated the scala code and information about the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pivot](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/RelationalGroupedDataset.html#pivot(pivotColumn:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset) on a grouped dataset to create columns from rows.

Given the set up:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import spark.implicits._

val base = Seq(
  ("id1", 1, "Android"),
  ("id2", 2, "Android"),
  ("id3", 1, "Android"),
  ("id4", 1, "iOS"),
  ("id5", 2, "Android")
).toDF("user_id", "gender", "platform")

val timeSeries = Seq(
  ("m1", 1, "Android", 22486, 48185),
  ("m1", 2, "Android", 15791, 48185),
  ("m1", 0, "Android", 18940, 48185),
  ("m2", 0, "Android", 16401, 40852),
  ("m2", 0, "Android", 16401, 40852),
  ("m2", 0, "iOS", 16401, 8475),
  ("m3", 0, "Android", 15507, 39472),
  ("m3", 1, "Android", 19205, 39472),
  ("m3", 2, "Android", 12999, 39472)
).toDF("time_prefix", "gender", "platform", "gender_lt7", "platform_lt7")
```

Then an implementation using pivot could be:

```
def createPivot(keyColumn: String, valueColumn: String) = {
  val df = timeSeries.groupBy(col(keyColumn))
      .pivot(col("time_prefix"))
      .agg(first(valueColumn))
  df.select(
    df.columns
      .map(name => if (name == keyColumn) col(name) else col(name).alias(s"${valueColumn}_$name")): _*
  )  
}

val genders = createPivot("gender",  "gender_lt7")
val platforms = createPivot("platform","platform_lt7")

base
  .join(genders, Seq("gender"))
  .join(platforms, Seq("platform"))
```

Which yields the result:

```
// +--------+------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
// |platform|gender|user_id|gender_lt7_m1|gender_lt7_m2|gender_lt7_m3|platform_lt7_m1|platform_lt7_m2|platform_lt7_m3|
// +--------+------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
// | Android|     1|    id1|        22486|         null|        19205|          48185|          40852|          39472|
// | Android|     2|    id2|        15791|         null|        12999|          48185|          40852|          39472|
// | Android|     1|    id3|        22486|         null|        19205|          48185|          40852|          39472|
// |     iOS|     1|    id4|        22486|         null|        19205|           null|           8475|           null|
// | Android|     2|    id5|        15791|         null|        12999|          48185|          40852|          39472|
// +--------+------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
//
```